# Prove $a_n$ and $b_n$ have the same limit

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Let x,y be positive, constant nambers so:

$a_1=x, b_1=y$ and
$a_{n+1}=(a_n+b_n)/2,\; b_{n+1}=\sqrt{a_nb_n}$

Prove that $a_n$ and $b_n$ have the same limit.

From inequality of arithmetic and geometric means, I know that $b_{n+1} \le a_{n+1}$ . I assume from it that $b_n \le a_n$
 I can prove that $a_n $ monotonically dicreasing  and $b_n$ is monotonically increasing. But how can I prove that $\lim_{n\to+\infty} (b_n-a_n)=0$?
If I prove it I can use Cantor's intersection theorem.

Sorry for inncorrect sintax and language.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic-geometric_mean